# Why does unlocking bootloader require erasing userdata?

Tags: factory-reset, bootloader, bootloader-lock

I unlocked the bootloader in my OnePlus 5 right after it was delivered, so there was nothing to erase. Then I flashed TWRP and SuperSU. It comes with DM-Verity (and `/data` force encrypted). I tried re-locking, but later I have to erase all data again before unlocking bootloader. So the questions are:

- Why is it required to erase all data when unlocking bootloader? Even with device encryption on?
- Can I avoid the erase?

Comment: And you second question, no you can't avoid it... that would defeat the whole purpose of why it is.

Comment: @acejavelin I edited my question

Comment: The answer linked doesn't change and still applies... If you unlock the bootloader, the first or hundredth time, regardless of encryption, it will wipe the device.

Comment: @Izzy Never heard of device-dependent cases! You broadened my horizons.

Comment: To clarify that last comment (on an exchange [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41377634#41377634)): One usually cannot avoid the erase. But I know of one single exception: For the LG P880, some XDA dev wrote an app to unlock the bootloader. This was a very specific case, permitting the user to unlock/relock up to 8 times while the normal procedure wouldn't allow that: the P880 uses "fuses" for this. Once burned, they're gone.